# How to obtain uuid auto-generated on client side when upload to s3 with FineUploader?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

i'd like to get the auto-generated uuid, How can i get it? I dont want to generate it my self.

```
...
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
    // uuid of uploaded file
    console.log(id,fileName,responseJSON);
},
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the getUuid method.  For example, given an ID (such as the one provided in your onComplete callback:

this.getUuid(id);

For more methods, have a look at the [methods documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods.html)